# Is it possible to access Face ID sensors raw data?

Tags: applications, security, sensors, front-camera, face-unlock

My Honor 10 has facial recognition capability in the dark, I suppose it works like Apple's Face ID which would rely on and IR camera and an Infrared pattern/dot projector.

So, since the Settings app and the Screen lock app can access those sensors, could it be possible to activate/ access those sensors data in another custom built app (on a Rooted smartphone) to use it for 3D scanning objects or simply recording the face of the user in order to 3D print a functional facial recognition "key"?

Answer (score 0):

FaceId is based on infrared light sensors and depth sensing technology.
All the captured data is saved in the form of Encrypted hashes in the secure enclave.
First of all, the system doesn't allow you to read these files. But in any case
you are able to read the encrypted files, you can not decrypt them for your purpose.

All the encrypted data is saved locally.

If you are creating a new app, you can use these sensors for capturing data.